Free running program captures wrong exception address
I'm using an ARM Cortex-A9 processor ZYNQ 7000. The processor raises an data abort exception if invalid address is accessed. The exception handler captures the data abort address, but if the program runs freely, the captured data abort address is wrong.
To find the data abort address, the link register is used. In the exception handler, lr - 8 is assigned to the DataAbortAddr global variable, as in the bsp library.
While this captured address is correct if the program runs step by step via a debugger, or if there is a breakpoint before the invalid address accessing instruction, it is wrong if the program runs freely.
Code for demo:
extern uint32_t DataAbortAddr;
void MyDataAbortHandler(void *arg) {
    (void)arg;
    printf("DataAbort at %p\n", (void *)(uintptr_t)DataAbortAddr);
    PrintBacktrace();
    SystemReset();
}
int TriggerDataAbort() {
    PrintBacktrace();
    printf("Accessing invalid address\n");
    int *invalidAddr = (int *)0x30001;
    int value = *invalidAddr;
    return value;
}
int main() {
    Init();
    TriggerDataAbort();
    ...
}

The assembly:
int TriggerDataAbort() {
  1010a0:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
  1010a4:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
  1010a8:   e24dd060    sub sp, sp, #96 ; 0x60
  ...
  10112c:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
  101130:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
  101134:   e50b3014    str r3, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec ; the exact instruction that causes data abort exception
  ...
}
int main() {
  101154:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
  101158:   e3001ff0    movw    r1, #4080   ; 0xff0
  ...
  101180:   ebffffc6    bl  1010a0 <TriggerDataAbort>
  101184:   e3040378    movw    r0, #17272  ; 0x4378
  101188:   e3400010    movt    r0, #16
  ...
}

If the program runs freely, the captured DataAbortAddr is always 0x101188, which is wrong. If it runs step by step, or hits a breakpoint at int value = *invalidAddr, DataAbortAddr is 0x101134, which is correct.
What might be the reason of the wrong DataAbortAddr? How to correctly capture the DataAbortAddr when the program runs freely?

Normally, you don't call printf() in a data abort handler.  Is MyDataAbortHandler() executing in the exception context?  Ie, it is DataAbortInterrupt() or called via some hook mechnics?  The functions you can call in this mode are likely limited.  Calling printf() will probably not work.  When you run freely, you probably get a double fault.

However, when stepping you won't see CPU pipeline.  The data aborts are imprecise.  The PC/LR are where an instruction is being fetched.  The data abort may not happen precisely.  You can add a dsb and other barriers to force an abort, before proceeding.  But I think this is probably normal.  Ie, 0x101188 is just after the return from TriggerDataAbort().

Thanks. MyDataAbortHandler is executing in the exception context. printf is implemented using UART blocking API so it works in the exception context.
